pgrouting and pgr_dijkstra driving side
I've been fiddling with pgrouting to snap points taken from a vehicle to the actual road geometries and then apply a pgr_dijkstra function to get a neat geometry alongside the road. This worked on a few attempts but it's giving some unpredictable results sometimes, which seem to me to be related with the driving side - I'm using UK data, where cars drive on the left.
WITH input_points AS (
    VALUES 
        (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.177026, 51.684535), 4326)),  -- Point 1
        (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.174392, 51.685590), 4326)),  -- Point 2
        (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.172121, 51.687115), 4326)),  -- Point 3
        (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.173587, 51.688641), 4326))   -- Point 4
),
-- Compute the bounding box for the input points
bbox AS (
    SELECT ST_Envelope(ST_Collect(ARRAY_AGG(column1))) AS geom
    FROM input_points
),
-- Select nearby roads using bounding box
nearby_roads AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM roads r
    WHERE r.geom && (SELECT geom FROM bbox)
    AND r.tags->>'highway' IN ('motorway', 'motorway_link', 'trunk', 'trunk_link', 'primary', 'primary_link', 'secondary', 'secondary_link', 'tertiary', 'tertiary_link', 'residential')
),
-- Snap points to road
snapped_points AS (
    SELECT
        ST_ClosestPoint(r.geom, tp.column1) AS snapped_geom,
        tp.column1 as original_geom,
        r.pgr_source,
        r.pgr_target,
        r.id AS road_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS row_num
    FROM input_points tp
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT * FROM nearby_roads r
        WHERE ST_DWithin(r.geom, tp.column1, 100)  -- Use 100 meters as the search radius
        ORDER BY ST_Distance(r.geom, tp.column1)
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS r
),
-- Calculate shortest path
shortest_path AS (
    SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
        $$
        SELECT id, pgr_source AS source,
        pgr_target AS target,
        ST_Length(geom) AS cost,
        CASE WHEN tags->>'oneway' = 'yes' THEN -1 ELSE ST_Length(geom) END AS reverse_cost
        FROM roads
        WHERE geom && (
            ST_Buffer(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[
                ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.177026, 51.684535), 4326),
                ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.174392, 51.685590), 4326),
                ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.172121, 51.687115), 4326),
                ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.173587, 51.688641), 4326)
            ]), 0.1)
        )
        AND tags->>'highway' IN ('motorway', 'motorway_link', 'trunk', 'trunk_link', 'primary', 'primary_link', 'secondary', 'secondary_link', 'tertiary', 'tertiary_link', 'residential')
        $$,
        (SELECT pgr_source FROM snapped_points ORDER BY row_num ASC LIMIT 1),
        (SELECT pgr_target FROM snapped_points ORDER BY row_num DESC LIMIT 1),
        false
    )
)

-- Select GeoJson with route (MultiLineString)
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Collect(geom)) as route_geojson
FROM nearby_roads r
JOIN shortest_path sp ON r.id = sp.edge;

This query isn't optimized, but the result is a MultiLineString that attempts to drive through the roads on the right side, instead of the roads where the points where snapped to.
I've confirmed the connectivity of the nodes and the roads and there aren't any leaks. As far as I know, there is no way to instruct a driving on the left option.
Below is a GeoJson containing the resulting MultiLineString and the snapped points for reference. Any guidance would be much appreciated...
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                -0.1754479,
                51.6848268
            ],
            [
                -0.1763754,
                51.684512
            ],
            [
                -0.1772001,
                51.6842766
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                -0.1708044,
                51.6857755
            ],
            [
                -0.1709694,
                51.6858436
            ],
            [
                -0.171137,
                51.685901
            ],
            [
                -0.1712483,
                51.6859289
            ],
            [
                -0.1714347,
                51.6859467
            ],
            [
                -0.1716292,
                51.6859368
            ],
            [
                -0.1717874,
                51.6859176
            ],
            [
                -0.1729109,
                51.6856113
            ],
            [
                -0.1738256,
                51.6853539
            ],
            [
                -0.1746647,
                51.6850412
            ],
            [
                -0.1754479,
                51.6848268
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                -0.1718266,
                51.6865757
            ],
            [
                -0.1720176,
                51.6867301
            ],
            [
                -0.1720777,
                51.6867946
            ],
            [
                -0.1721191,
                51.6868697
            ],
            [
                -0.1721513,
                51.6869774
            ],
            [
                -0.172119,
                51.6871178
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                -0.172119,
                51.6871178
            ],
            [
                -0.1721102,
                51.6872179
            ],
            [
                -0.1721093,
                51.6873112
            ],
            [
                -0.1721139,
                51.687433
            ],
            [
                -0.1721451,
                51.6875116
            ],
            [
                -0.1721736,
                51.6875866
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                -0.1732967,
                51.6884405
            ],
            [
                -0.1732259,
                51.6883854
            ],
            [
                -0.1731924,
                51.6883594
            ],
            [
                -0.1721736,
                51.6875866
            ]
        ]
    ]
},
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#6695e1",
        "stroke-width": 4,
        "stroke-opacity": 1
      },
      "id": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "marker-color": "#385be5",
        "marker-size": "medium",
        "marker-symbol": "circle-stroked"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.17701249347306017,
          51.684487226765704
        ]
      },
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "marker-color": "#385be5"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.17439718700248355,
          51.685599690907324
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "marker-color": "#385be5"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.1721197123119961,
          51.68711470375838
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "marker-color": "#385be5"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.17357479387940516,
          51.688656700695084
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

